# Trying to parse firebase auth token using small rye and google public key, but getting invalid signature error

Tags: firebase-authentication, jwt, quarkus, smallrye

I have a quarkus project with following smallrye settings:

```
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=META-INF/resources/key.pem
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=true
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=https://securetoken.google.com/firebase-project-id
```

I have downloaded keys from [google public key](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com%20and%20put%20it%20into%20keys.pem)
I am getting following error:

> Failed to verify token

Comment: Do you have more log information? Additional stacktrace information?

Comment: I realized I should use stolen from firebase>aur>currentUser.getIdToken which I m able to validate. I was previously creating firebase custom token which was not correct way